# GWT: Accessing i18n messages in server code

Tags: java, gwt

I have an interface that extends the `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages` class, which I use for retrieving i18n messages in my GWT application.  It looks like this:

```
public interface MyMessages extends com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages {
  @DefaultMessage("Hello world")
  @Key("message1")
  String message1();

  @DefaultMessage("Hello again")
  @Key("message2")
  String message2();

  //...
}
```

Normally, I create an instance of it using `GWT.create()` like so:

```
private MyMessages messages = GWT.create(MyMessages.class);
```

However, this does not work with server-side code, only client-side code (it throws an error saying that GWT.create() is only usable in client-side code).

The answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503283/gwt-i18n-on-the-server-side) points to a separate library that you can download which will let you access the i18n messages on the server, but I don't want to download any extra libraries (this seems like a simple problem, there must be a simple solution).

In summary: **How can I access my i18n messages in server-side code?**  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the server side you can use the standard Java localization tools like [ResourceBundle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).
Look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html) for a tutorial how to use it.

```
// Create a ResourceBundle out of your property files
ResourceBundle labels =
  ResourceBundle.getBundle("LabelsBundle", currentLocale);

// Get localized value
String value = labels.getString(key);
```

The GWT specific way of creating an interface out of your property files and providing implementations via deferred binding can not be used on sever side Java.

If you are fearless and willing to spend the time, you can implement a code generation step to read your property files and generate implementation classes for your message interface. That's exactly what the Google GWT compiler does behind the scene.

Comment: I use Maven with my GWT project and one nice thing about that is that it looks at your Messages.properties file and automatically generates a Messages interface for you.  Using a ResourceBundle works, but I still hate having to do something separate for server-side code.  Maybe Google is saying, "A well designed application shouldn't need to access i18n messages on the server-side."

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I think it makes sense for the messages to be accessible only to the client.  The server is always going to have the same locale, so it will always return the same messages no matter what locale the client is in.  For example, if the server is located in California, it will always retrieve English messages because the default locale of the server uses  English.  When compiled to Javascript, GWT probably does some magic to determine the locale of the web user and use the appropriate .properties file.

Comment: @Michael that's why the libraries you rejected (and I understand your motivation!) makes the client to set the locale on the server side... Using Renato's message code system is a way, although it makes hard to customize the messages ("Cannot open file 'foo'" and similar).

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Michael.. I was having this problem of trying to "localize" messages generated on the server.... but I decided to instead just throw an Exception on the server (because it is an error message which should only happen exceptionally) which contains the message code, which the client code can then look up and show the correct localized message to the user.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good solution.  That's what I was going to do, but I was lazy and decided to just access the Messages.properties file on the server because my app will ever only use one language. :)

Comment: Good idea. Sometime we have to pass additional information, but it can be included as a parameter of the specific exception.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great library for GWT internationalization [gwt-dmesg](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dmesg/). It allows you to 'share' .properties files between clent and server. However, project looks to be abandoned by author and you must recompile it manually for use with GWT versio >= 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

GWT.create() can only be used in client-side code.

The good thing to do is that you provide your own I18NProvider class/interface, from which then you can extend to server side I18N factory and client side I18N factory read the same resource bundle.

After that you can simply use it all over your system, unify your code.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Are you saying that I could create one class that can be used to retrieve messages on both the client and server?  That would be great.  Right now, I'm using separate classes for each.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes that's the point, separate classes are good enough, thing is it might be better that you can create a facade to access two different classes at the runtime, that will save you lots of time, and give you neater code.

Answer (score 0):

Following vanje's answer, and considering the encoding used for the properties files (which can be troublesome as ResourceBundle uses by default "ISO-8859-1", here is the solution I came up with:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MyResourceBundle {

    // feature variables
    private ResourceBundle bundle;
    private String fileEncoding;

    public MyResourceBundle(Locale locale, String fileEncoding){
        this.bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.app.Bundle", locale);
        this.fileEncoding = fileEncoding;
    }

    public MyResourceBundle(Locale locale){
        this(locale, "UTF-8");
    }

    public String getString(String key){
        String value = bundle.getString(key); 
        try {
            return new String(value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), fileEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

The way to use this would be very similar than the regular ResourceBundle usage:

```
private MyResourceBundle labels = new MyResourceBundle("es", "UTF-8");
String label = labels.getString(key)
```

Or you can use the alternate constructor which uses UTF-8 by default:

```
private MyResourceBundle labels = new MyResourceBundle("es");
```