# in GWT, can we manage Messages & Constants (i18n) at Server as we manage at Client?

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp

Messages & Constants (`com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Constants` & `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages`) in GWT allow us to put all Messages &  Constants into `properties` files so that we can change these messages &  constants at any time we want without the need to recompile the whole webapp when we need to change them.

Ex: you have a message call "`User451 pls views order`" in `myMessages.properties`

```
userViewOrder=User''{0}'' pls views order
```

& in the `MyMessages.java`

```
public interface MyMessages extends Messages{
    String userViewOrder(String userID);
}
```

At a later time, the bos wants to change the message to "`Customer451 pls views order`" then we don't need to recompile the whole project but just need to modify the `myMessages.properties` file

```
userViewOrder=Customer''{0}'' pls views order
```

So my question is, can we achieve the similar thing at the server level?

For example, in server, after inserting order data successfully into DB we need to send a private message to the customer immediately right at the server. Ex:

```
public boolean isertOrder(String data, String userID){
    String sql="insert query here";
    ..... more code ....
    int resultCode=prepareStmt.executeUpdate();
    if (resultCode==1){
       //insert a notification into Message table 
       String msg="Congratulation user "+userID+", You ordered successfully!"; 
// how to manage this message without needing to recompiling the whole project

       String sql="insert into Message values (.....)"
       ///do the inserting here
    }
}
```

can we manage Messages & Constants (i18n) at Server as we manage at Client?

Can we be able to do that?

& more importantly, Can we do it safely?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503283/gwt-i18n-on-the-server-side

Comment: Or this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714278/gwt-get-constants-in-server-side

Comment: i used Hermes, but it got this err: [WARN] Server class 'com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath

Comment: i fixed "extends ConstantsWithLookup" but the warning is still there